# Pointwise and uniform convergence of this series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1- \frac{1}{2n}\right)^{-n^2}(x^2-1)^n$$
I've tried treating it as a power series centered around $x = 1$ and $x = -1$ and using root test I arrive to radius of convergence $R = \frac{1}{\sqrt e}$. However the graph seems to indicate the radius of convergence is much smaller.
Also, how to determine if it is uniformly convergent? I only know about Weierstrass M-test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a_n = \left(1- \frac{1}{2n}\right)^{-n^2}(x^2-1)^n$. Then 
$$
|a_n|^{1/n} =  \left(1- \frac{1}{2n}\right)^{-n}|x^2-1| \to \sqrt{e} |x^2-1|
$$
as $n \to \infty$. Consequently the series converges uniformly if 
$$
|x^2-1| < \frac{1}{\sqrt{e}} - \varepsilon
$$
for any $\varepsilon > 0$. These sets are unions of two intervals.

**Added** If $|x^2 - 1| = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}$, then $|a_n|^{1/n} = (1 - \frac{1}{2n})^{-n}e^{-1/2} = f(-1/2)$ where $f(x) = (1+x/n)^ne^{-x}$. One can compute that $f'(x) = \frac{x}{n}(1+x/n)^{n-1}e^{-x}$. This is negative if $-n < x < 0$. Since also $f(0) = 1$, therefore $f(-1/2) > 1$. Therefore also $|a_n| > 1$ at the endpoints of the convergence intervals and  the series does not converge at these endpoints.

Comment: "If $|x^2 - 1| = \pm \frac{1}{\sqrt{e}}$, then $|a_n|^{1/n} > 1$" Can you prove this part? If you use root test again the limit is $1$.

Comment: @hallaplay835 - see the edit to the answer.

Comment: Thanks. Also, what result are you using to establish uniform convergence? The result makes sense if you think of the series as a power series centered at $1$ and $-1$ and applying [Cauchy-Hadamard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Hadamard_theorem), but strictly speaking it is not a power series, isn't it?

Comment: This should not be viewed as a power series but rather as a series of functions which converges uniformly, say of the form $\sum_n g_n(x)$. The argument in my answer implies that $ \lim_{n \to \infty} \sup_{x \in I} |g_n(x)|^{1/n} \to \lambda$ for some set $I$ and some $\lambda < 1$. Therefore $|g_n(x)| \le C \lambda^n$ for all $x \in I$ and all $n$, with a fixed constant $C$. Consequently $\sum_n g_n(x)$ converges uniformly on this set $I$.

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$u_n=\left(1- \frac{1}{2n}\right)^{-n^2}(x^2-1)^n$$

Notice that
$$\left(1- \frac{1}{2n}\right)^{-n^2}\sim_\infty e^{\frac n2}$$
so 
$$|u_n|\sim_\infty e^{\frac n2}|x^2-1|^n$$
so by the ratio test we have
$$\frac{|u_{n+1}|}{|u_n|}\sim_\infty e^{1/2}|x^2-1|<1\iff 1-e^{-1/2}<x^2<1+e^{-1/2}$$